# Given unimodular matrices $A, B$, solve the matrix equation $T^\top A T = B$

Tags: matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations, integer-lattices, unimodular-matrices

Given two symmetric integer [unimodular matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix) $A$ and $B$ with $\det A = \det B = \pm 1$. How do we find any integer unimodular matrices $T$ such that
$$
T^\top A T = B?
$$

Here $T^\top$, denotes the transpose of $T$. As an example, here are the data from the Mathematica Table:

```
A = ({{2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {-1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}    });
 
B = ({{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}    });
```

In matrix form,

$$A=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
such that $\det A=\det B=-1$ here. Can you solve integer matrix $T$ with $T^\top A T = B$?

Comment: In Sagemath you can compute it but matrices `A` and `B` must be positive definite matrices. I do not know why their algorithm works only with such matrices.

Comment: we have det A and det B is $-1$ in general $\pm 1$ here.

Comment: Thanks for Sagemath, where can I find codes for this?

Comment: It is not about determinant but about `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ` that gives False in `Mathematica`.

Answer (score 4):

For positive definite integer matrices, one can compute an integer transformation matrix using Magma's `IsIsometric(L, LL)` command, where `L` and `LL` are two lattices. Relevant pieces of documentation are [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/354#3464) and (about the Automorphism Group and Isometry Testing) [here](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/354).

Matrices in your example *are not positive definite*. I will briefly explain why the determination of the transformation matrix for them is a very difficult problem. But for the sake of example consider first the isometrism of the positive definite Gram matrices $A^2$ and $B^2=I$.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 5 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -4 & 7 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

It can be found in the [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) as follows:

```
L := LatticeWithGram(Matrix(Integers(), 10, 10, [5, -4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4, 6, -4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -4, 7, -4, 1, 0, 0, -4, 0, 0, 0, 1, -4, 6, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -4, 6, -4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -4, 6, -4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]));
LL := LatticeWithGram(Matrix(Integers(), 10, 10, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]));
IsIsometric(L, LL);
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 7 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 8 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
 5 & 10 & 15 & 12 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 0 & 0 \\
 6 & 12 & 18 & 15 & 12 & 8 & 4 & 9 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 14 & 20 & 16 & 12 & 8 & 4 & 10 & 0 & 0 \\
 8 & 16 & 24 & 20 & 15 & 10 & 5 & 12 & 0 & 0 \\
 10 & 20 & 30 & 24 & 18 & 12 & 6 & 15 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
We can verify that

$$ T A^2 T^T=I.$$

Why this does not work if matrices are not positive definite? Let us come back to your example. For the sake of making a stronger point, invert the original equation:

$$T^T BT=A^{-1}.$$

Here I use that $B^{-1}=B$. The inverse of $A$ is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 4 & 7 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 14 & 20 & 16 & 12 & 8 & 4 & 10 & 0 & 0 \\
 10 & 20 & 30 & 24 & 18 & 12 & 6 & 15 & 0 & 0 \\
 8 & 16 & 24 & 20 & 15 & 10 & 5 & 12 & 0 & 0 \\
 6 & 12 & 18 & 15 & 12 & 8 & 4 & 9 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 8 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 5 & 10 & 15 & 12 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Consider the diagonal elements, i.e.,
$d=\{4,14,30,20,12,6,2,8,1,-1\}$. They should be obtained as values of the quadratic form

$$
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2+x_6^2+x_7^2+x_8^2+x_9^2-x_{10}^2=d_k.
$$

Last minus sign is the problem--it prevents an efficient searching procedure. For the all positive case (positive definiteness), $x_i\le\sqrt{d_k}$ and therefore exhaustive search can be performed by brute force, or by more efficient methods such as implemented in Magma or described in the paper *Congruence of rational matrices defined by an integer matrix* ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2022.127639)). If matrices are not positive semidefinite, the search space is unlimited: $x_i$ can be a very big number.